# Php Javascript alternative for jquery grid

Tags: javascript, php, prototypejs

I want an alternative to a jquery grid for crud operations in php. I want to use a simple table with facilities such as searching, sorting an pagination. Is there any library for this? Can i use prototype.js for achieving this?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

The only jQuery library out there that sort of is what you need is jqGrid.  I am sufficiently unhappy with it that I am in the middle of writing my own grid for CRUD.  FlexiGrid is better code and looks nicer but it is missing a lot.  jqGrid is fairly complete but I personally don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out dhtmlXGrid:
http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/index.shtml

It interacts with JavaScript, and you can easily come up with a PHP integration from there.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a relatively common problem. I prefer SDTable for dynamic grids. [Download link](http://www.sdtable.com)