# oncheck event update table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a simple question here.
I need to UPDATE a row table by selecting a check-box in my page,
what is the quickl way to do that? Ajax?

I would like to find a good source of **Using Ajax with php and mysql**
If someone know, I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here:

[Best data grid for php based application using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171596/best-data-grid-for-php-based-application-using-ajax)

[PHP Grid recommendations needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664946/php-grid-recommendations-needed)

[Grid View using javascript or in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966785/grid-view-using-javascript-or-in-php)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887675/editable-grid-php

[Php Javascript alternative for jquery grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036737/php-javascript-alternative-for-jquery-grid)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345117/best-free-php-grid-required-closed

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+data+grid

Sounds like you want a datagrid component...

Comment: perhaps the guy give a downvote cause hate my question!! ha!!

Comment: Thank You Very Nuch for the references, it will be very useful. Datagrid do not solve the problem to me, but th ideas inside code will help me a lot. cool!

Comment: Your welcome, feel free to upvote the answer out of negativity too!